# display:block breaking the float in IE6

Tags: css, menu, cross-browser

The code below works fine in Safari and Firefox but not in IE6. It's when I include the `display:block` for `#horNav  li  a`. The float breaks in IE6. Is there a way to have `display:block` and not to break the float? If I include width for `#horNav  li` it will work, but I don't want to specify the width for it as the the width may vary.

CSS:

```
#horNav{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    border: 0px solid #486B02;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Arial;
}
#horNav  li{
    float:left;
}
#horNav  li  a {
    display:block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:0 40 0 19;
    border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="horNav">
    <li><a>Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried `inline-block`?

Comment: Are you sure, it's not another property that meddles around? The a{display:block} in li{float:left} was quite common even years ago and should work just fine. Could you create a jsFiddle with the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `float: left` to the `a` as well. You will not then need `display: block;` on the `a` as well because a floated element is automatically a block

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Remove float:left; for #horNav li and add

```
#horNav li { display: inline-block; }
```

I think you can remove line-height and height for #horNav li a

Comment: Create IE6 contitional file and give it display: inline.